# python error could not install packages due to an environmenterror winerror 5 access is denied

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I get the following error when i tried to install scipy.state . I am running pip3 on a windows 10 machine with Python 3.8.1.

-I have installed Scipy first

**C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip3 install scipy
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in c:\users\elnaz khatmi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.3 in c:\users\elnaz khatmi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from scipy) (1.18.1)**

-and then i installed scipy.state but i see an error:

**C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip3 install scipy.stats
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement scipy.stats (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for scipy.stats**

I tried to uninstall and reinstall it but i have got the following error

**C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip3 install --upgrade --force-reinstall --user scipy.stats
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement scipy.stats (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for scipy.stats**

Answer (score 1):

You just have to install scipy.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip3 install scipy
```

Once scipy is installed, scipy.stats is usable in python with :

```
from scipy import stats
```

Comment: I already installed scipy and i did not face any problem with it.

Comment: C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip3 install scipy
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in c:\users\elnaz khatmi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.3 in c:\users\elnaz khatmi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from scipy) (1.18.1)

Comment: I edited my answer. You do not have install sub-package, pip gets everything you can need.

Comment: actually all error that I received in python is about my scipy.state is not import yet..

Comment: I can't find anything about scipy.state . Do you mean scipy.stats ? And before using a module, you have to import it, otherwise it does no work.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are trying to do exactly ? (I mean a part of code)

Comment: Trying to analyze some data using python distribution-fitting

Comment: In other words, a python script that checks a set of data against more than 80 different distributions.

Comment: after installed scipy i tried 'from scipy import stats' and I have got more errors that says :  'ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found'

Comment: You should edit your question to add the complete error, with the stacktrace if you have one.